# Как решить проблему с ошибкой при использовании mysqli_fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

При работе с базой данных выдаёт пустой результат, точнее выдаёт ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in Z:\home\admin.uz\www\second.php on line 20
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   Z:\home\admin.uz\www\second.php on line 20

Вот код:

```
//1.Create a db connection
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "pavel");
define("DB_PASS", "2604545");
define("DB_NAME", "inhaur");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
//Test if connection succed
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("Database connection failed: ".
    mysqli_connect_error().
    "(" . mysqli_connect_errno(). ")"
);
}

$query  = "SELECT 'id' FROM 'pages'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$arrayOf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die("ERROR: ".mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Прочитал, но решить проблему всё равно не получается

Comment: @Павел тогда может быть это поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос - просто коллекция ошибок и опечаток.

1. имена полей и таблиц в mysql не берутся в кавычки.
2. `or die("ERROR: ".mysqli_error());` имело бы смысл писать с `mysqli_query`, но и там это будет вредно и неправильно.
3. Откуда берется `NULL` - загадка. По идее ошибочный запрос должен вернуть FALSE и в сообщении об ошибке должно быть написано `boolean` а не `NULL`. Видимо, еще какая-то опечатка.

Исправляем запрос, убираем `or die` и добавляем перед коннектом строчку из ответа по ссылке

Comment: Без ковычек тоже пробовал ,таже самая ошибка